# Apache Nifi and OPC integration issue (GetValue processor)

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi, opc, opc-ua, hortonworks-dataflow

I have integrated NIFI OPC UA [https://github.com/wadesalazar/NIFI-OPCUA] processor with Apache Nifi 1.3.I am following this URL [https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/90355/collect-data-from-opc-ua-protocol.html] to get started. I have installed a simulation OPC server from prosys opc ua on windows.

I am able to pull messages from the GetNodeIDs processor on NIFI, and splitText processor is being used for reading messages line by line and sending to GetValue processor as shown in the example, but my GetValue processor is continuously throwing below error.

I tried to set "starting node" property in GetNodeIDs processor, but not able to make out what a node property should I set, please find below my sample data from simulation server.

Sample data received from simulation opc server:

```
nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=85
- nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2253
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2004
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2007
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2009
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2010
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2011
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2012
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11489
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11527
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2006
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2742
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2005
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2008
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2256
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2138
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2257
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2258
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2259
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2260
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2992
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2993
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2268
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2013
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2996
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2997
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11192
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11704
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2271
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2272
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2736
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2269
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2737
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=3704
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11703
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2735
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11702
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2274
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2020
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2275
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2290
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=3706
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2294
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2295
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2033
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2296
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2034
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=3709
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11313
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11314
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11312
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11492
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11493
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11494
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11715
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=11645
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=12637
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=12581
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=12642
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=12672
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=12675
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=12641
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=12710
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=12639
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=12640
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=12711
- - ns=2;s=MyObjectsFolder
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - - ns=2;s=MyDevice
- - - ns=2;s=MyDevice
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2255
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=68
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2994
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=68
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2254
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=68
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2267
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=68
- ns=2;s=MyObjectsFolder
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - ns=2;s=MyDevice
- - - ns=2;s=MyDeviceType
- - - ns=2;s=MyEnumObject
- - - ns=2;s=MyLevel
- - - ns=2;s=MyLevel
- - - ns=2;s=MyLevel.Alarm
- - - ns=2;s=MyMethod
- - - ns=2;s=MySwitch
- - ns=2;s=MyDevice
- - - ns=2;s=MyDeviceType
- - - ns=2;s=MyEnumObject
- - - ns=2;s=MyLevel
- - - ns=2;s=MyLevel
- - - ns=2;s=MyLevel.Alarm
- - - ns=2;s=MyMethod
- - - ns=2;s=MySwitch
- ns=3;s=StaticData
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - ns=3;s=AccessLevels
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - - ns=3;s=AccessLevelCurrentRead
- - - ns=3;s=AccessLevelCurrentReadNotUser
- - - ns=3;s=AccessLevelCurrentReadWrite
- - - ns=3;s=AccessLevelCurrentWrite
- - - ns=3;s=AccessLevelCurrentWriteNotUser
- - ns=3;s=AnalogItemArrays
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - - ns=3;s=ByteAnalogItemArray
- - - ns=3;s=DoubleAnalogItemArray
- - - ns=3;s=FloatAnalogItemArray
- - - ns=3;s=Int16AnalogItemArray
- - - ns=3;s=Int32AnalogItemArray
- - - ns=3;s=Int64AnalogItemArray
- - - ns=3;s=SByteAnalogItemArray
- - - ns=3;s=UInt16AnalogItemArray
- - - ns=3;s=UInt32AnalogItemArray
- - - ns=3;s=UInt64AnalogItemArray
- - ns=3;s=AnalogItems
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - - ns=3;s=ByteAnalogItem
- - - ns=3;s=DoubleAnalogItem
- - - ns=3;s=FloatAnalogItem
- - - ns=3;s=Int16AnalogItem
- - - ns=3;s=Int32AnalogItem
- - - ns=3;s=Int64AnalogItem
- - - ns=3;s=SByteAnalogItem
- - - ns=3;s=Sample Instrument Int32AnalogItem
- - - ns=3;s=UInt16AnalogItem
- - - ns=3;s=UInt32AnalogItem
- - - ns=3;s=UInt64AnalogItem
- - ns=3;s=DataItems
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - - ns=3;s=BooleanDataItem
- - - ns=3;s=ByteDataItem
- - - ns=3;s=ByteStringDataItem
- - - ns=3;s=DateTimeDataItem
- - - ns=3;s=DoubleDataItem
- - - ns=3;s=FloatDataItem
- - - ns=3;s=GUIDDataItem
- - - ns=3;s=Int16DataItem
- - - ns=3;s=Int32DataItem
- - - ns=3;s=Int64DataItem
- - - ns=3;s=SByteDataItem
- - - ns=3;s=StringDataItem
- - - ns=3;s=UInt16DataItem
- - - ns=3;s=UInt32DataItem
- - - ns=3;s=UInt64DataItem
- - - ns=3;s=XmlElementDataItem
- - ns=3;s=DeepFolder
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - - ns=3;s=DeepObject01
- - ns=3;s=MultiStateItems
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - - ns=3;s=MultiStateDiscreteItem
- - ns=3;s=StaticArrayVariables
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - - ns=3;s=BooleanArray
- - - ns=3;s=ByteArray
- - - ns=3;s=ByteStringArray
- - - ns=3;s=DateTimeArray
- - - ns=3;s=DoubleArray
- - - ns=3;s=FloatArray
- - - ns=3;s=GUIDArrayArray
- - - ns=3;s=Int16Array
- - - ns=3;s=Int32Array
- - - ns=3;s=Int64Array
- - - ns=3;s=LocalizedTextArray
- - - ns=3;s=QualifiedNameArray
- - - ns=3;s=SByteArray
- - - ns=3;s=StringArray
- - - ns=3;s=UInt16Array
- - - ns=3;s=UInt32Array
- - - ns=3;s=UInt64Array
- - - ns=3;s=VariantArray
- - - ns=3;s=XmlElementArray
- - ns=3;s=StaticVariables
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - - ns=3;s=Boolean
- - - ns=3;s=Byte
- - - ns=3;s=ByteString
- - - ns=3;s=DateTime
- - - ns=3;s=Double
- - - ns=3;s=Duration
- - - ns=3;s=Enumeration
- - - ns=3;s=Float
- - - ns=3;s=GUID
- - - ns=3;s=Image
- - - ns=3;s=ImageBMP
- - - ns=3;s=ImageGIF
- - - ns=3;s=ImageJPG
- - - ns=3;s=ImagePNG
- - - ns=3;s=Int16
- - - ns=3;s=Int32
- - - ns=3;s=Int64
- - - ns=3;s=Integer
- - - ns=3;s=LocaleId
- - - ns=3;s=LocalizedText
- - - ns=3;s=NodeId
- - - ns=3;s=Number
- - - ns=3;s=QualifiedName
- - - ns=3;s=SByte
- - - ns=3;s=String
- - - ns=3;s=Time
- - - ns=3;s=UInt16
- - - ns=3;s=UInt32
- - - ns=3;s=UInt64
- - - ns=3;s=UInteger
- - - ns=3;s=UtcTime
- - - ns=3;s=Variant
- - - ns=3;s=XmlElement
- - ns=3;s=TwoStateItems
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - - ns=3;s=TwoStateDiscreteItem
- ns=4;s=NonUaNodeComplianceTest
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - ns=4;s=ByteString
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=SByte
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Time
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=String
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Int16
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Image
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=DateTime
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=LocalizedText
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=UtcTime
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=LocaleId
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=ImageGIF
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Number
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Int32
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=ImageBMP
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=UInteger
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Boolean
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=UInt64
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Enumeration
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=QualifiedName
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=GUID
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Duration
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Double
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Variant
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Integer
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Float
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=ImagePNG
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Int64
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=Byte
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=NodeId
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=XmlElement
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=UInt16
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=ImageJPG
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- - ns=4;s=UInt32
- - - ns=4;s=NonUaNodeDataItemType
- ns=5;s=85/0:Simulation
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - ns=5;s=Counter1
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63
- - ns=5;s=Expression1
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63
- - ns=5;s=Random1
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63
- - ns=5;s=Sawtooth1
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63
- - ns=5;s=SimulationServerNode11
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63
- - ns=5;s=Sinusoid1
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63
- - ns=5;s=Square1
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63
- - ns=5;s=Triangle1
- - - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63
- ns=6;s=MyBigNodeManager
- - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=61
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0000
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0001
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0002
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0003
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0004
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0005
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0006
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0007
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0008
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0009
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0010
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0011
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0012
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0013
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0014
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0015
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0016
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0017
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0018
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0019
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0020
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0021
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0022
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0023
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0024
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0025
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0026
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0027
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0028
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0029
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0030
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0031
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0032
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0033
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0034
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0035
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0036
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0037
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0038
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
- - ns=6;s=DataItem_0039
- - - ns=6;s=DataItemType
```

Exception:

```
2017-07-25 18:03:10,189 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] c.k.nifi.nifi_opcua_bundle.GetValue GetValue[id=55c6ac28-015d-1000-076b-844ca709cc40] GetValue[id=55c6ac28-015d-1000-076b-844ca709cc40] failed to process due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid string representation of a nodeId: - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63; rolling back session: {}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid string representation of a nodeId: - nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.builtintypes.NodeId.parseNodeId(NodeId.java:383)
    at com.kentender.nifi.nifi_opcua_services.StandardOPCUAService.getValue(StandardOPCUAService.java:346)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.kentender.nifi.nifi_opcua_bundle.GetValue$2.process(GetValue.java:160)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2529)
    at com.kentender.nifi.nifi_opcua_bundle.GetValue.onTrigger(GetValue.java:156)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1120)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
```

Comment: Guys any help on this will really appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=63' represents an ExpandedNodeId, so the Nifi code should use ExpandedNodeId.parseExpandedNodeId() instead of NodeId.parseNodeId().

Or alternatively, you need to convert the ExpandedNodeId to NodeId before you pass it to GetValue(). Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Nifi, so I am not sure which is the correct approach here.

The problem arises from OPC UA "dualism" - some services like Browse, provide ExpandedNodeId references, whereas other services like Read, expect to get NodeId instances.

ExpandedNodeId may define the namespace as an URI ('nsu' in the string) or index ('ns' in the string), where as NodeId may only define the namespace as an index.

Comment: @ Jouni Aro Thanks for the info, but it seems like doing a code change at Nifi end will not be possible for me too.. Cant we adjust something in prosys simulation software itself to generate messages from Read not from Browse?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Simulation Server is using the NamespaceURI for some nodes, when returning references for Browse. You could change the ExpandedNodeId to NodeId in your application. That will require that you retrieve the NamespaceTable from the server, which is normally an SDK level feature, though.